# Qt, QWizard, QWizardPage and Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qwidget, qt-designer

I have a project where I would really like to use the Designer to visually design my wizard.

When I first did this, I had the QWizard widget and each QWizardPage in seperate .ui files and then built the wizard by calling addPages(). This worked but was messy because my project suddenly had one set of .h/.cpp/.ui files per page in the wizard.

Then I realized the designer could add QWizardPage's to a QWizard itself and "promote" pages too so that I could use my own class functionality. With that, I just had one .ui file for the QWizard and only two sets of .h/.cpp files (one for the QWizard and one for each QWizardPage).

So, my project looks kinda like this:

- Wizard.ui - contains all GUI elements for the wizard and
  corresponding pages
- Wizard.h/.cpp - contains code for the QWizard derived class
- WizardPages.h/.cpp - contains code for each QWizardPage

This worked great! Until I started adding implementation. The first thing I wanted to do was register a field in the first page (say WizardPage1).

```
WizardPage1::WizardPage1(QWidget* parent)
    : QWizardPage(parent)
{
    this->registerField("text*", textLineEdit);
}
```

But 'textLineEdit' is actually a member of the QWizard object. So, I figured I could register the field by using the QWizardPage's parent, however the generated code in the ui_Wizard.h file creates the QWizardPage objects without a parent. And when I try this:

```
Wizard::Wizard(QWidget *parent)
    : QWizard(parent)
{
    setupUi(this); // Wizard inherits QWizard and the deginer generated class

    // 'WizardPage1' is also the class name and variable name as
    // generated by Qt
    WizardPage1->setParent(this);
}
```

But this causes a crash when I do:

```
Wizard* wizard = new Wizard(this);
wizard->open(); // crashes
```

Has anyone tried something like what I'm trying to accomplish and gotten it to work?

Comment: try `QDialog::exec()` instead.
`open()` returns immediately. It's hard to tell, but I presume something is destroyed already when you call that. Can't tell more without full code listing.